# How can I transfer purchased apps to another Live Account?

Tags: apps, accounts, transfer

I have a Windows Phone 8 which I log on to with an old Live account. I now also have a Windows 8 tablet but I have used a newer Live account for that one. I now want to change the account on my phone so that both share my contact list on Exchange.

How do I transfers purchased apps from my old Live account to my new Live account so that I can just use the new account on both devices?

Thanks.

P.S. Alternatively, if there's a way

Comment: Did you write the P.S. part as you want? Looks like there is no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work with your account scenario, but I have done a similar in the past with some accounts of my own.

If you already have an old and new microsoft account, [migrate the xbox gamer tag](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/billing-and-subscriptions/account-management/switch-gamertag-to-different-microsoft-account) to the new account.

1. Log in with the account you want to change
2. Go to Settings and select **Account**
3. Scroll right to **Your Information** and select Account Security.
4. Select **Microsoft account**
5. If you already have another Microsoft account, select **Yes**, otherwise [create a Microsoft Account](http://login.live.com/)
6. Enter the password for the Microsoft account that is currently
   associated with your gamertag and select **Sign in**
7. Enter the email address and the password for the new Microsoft account that you want
   to associate with your gamertag, and then select **Sign in**
8. Select Yes,
   change to change the Microsoft account associated with your Xbox
   LIVE account
9. And Finally, Select **Update Contact Information** to
   update your contact information or Done to finish

These are the steps that I took to transfer phone contacts to another Microsoft account. I did not have two existing accounts though and do not know how it will work in your exact scenario.

One caveat is that you will have to re-download all content manually. When you go to the store, the buttons will still say buy, but once you tap them it will provide a message to the effect of "You have previously purchased this already, do you wish to download?". You will not be charged again.