# Is it possible to send an installed App to another Windows Phone?

Tags: 8.0, apps, nokia-lumia-525, nokia-lumia-930

I'm just messing around to find the way to share an App or a game between two Lumia phones. I have tried to find the solution but I did not succeed yet. The two Lumia phones are a Lumia 525 and a Lumia 930.

Thanks in advance.

**Updated**:
For example, I have the game installed name "ABC" and I want to share this game to another Lumia phone of mines. Except for sharing the link to the game page on the Store, how can I send this game to another Lumia phone?.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "share"? Send a Store link to the app from one phone to another? Install an app on one phone and have it automatically install on the other? Share app *data* (e.g. savegames) between the phones? Something else entirely?

Comment: @Indrek see updated question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/2553/106

Comment: Or even: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/692/106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing the store link is the easiest way as you can't transfer an app and app-data through bluetooth, wifi etc.

You could make a full device backup on one phone and restore it on another after a hard reset. This way you can copy some of the app data (depending on how the developer saved your data) to another device.

Comment: So finally I got That install through App Store , there is no other option to send installed apps.